# Root bracketing in complex space

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, roots

I have some function $F(\omega): \mathbb R\to\mathbb C$. The function $F(\omega)$ has both roots and singularities. Fortunately, I can calculate positions of singularities analytically.

So my problem is to find roots inside domain between singularities. Here I have  difficulty, because I cannot estimate if there is one, many or none roots inside the domain. Now I scan $\omega$ through the domain for change of simultaneous change of real and imaginary part of $F(\omega)$, what is both inaccurate and ineffective.

If there some method to estimate number of roots inside a domain?

I don't know if this is a right place to post questions about computational math, so don't hesitate to show me the right place to post :)

Comment: If $C$ is a closed contour that does not enclose any singularity then the number of zeroes inside $C$ is given by
$$\int_C\frac{F'}{F}d\omega.$$

If there are poles enclosed by $C$ you have to add them to the result to get the only the number of zeroes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try this technique, the problem here is computation of $F'$. Am I right that contour can be just a segment in real axis?

Comment: I forgot the factor $(2 \pi i)^{-1}$.

Comment: @galadog no, the contour must be a closed loop in the plane.  That integral calculates the number of zeros inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

See [Computing the Zeros of Analytic Functions](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/computational+science+%26+engineering/book/978-3-540-67162-6) for theory and code.

Despite the title, it handles computing zeros and poles of meromorphic functions.

Comment: Are we sure that the above reference really helps? From looking at the statement of the question, it appears we are talking about a function from the reals into the complex plane, rather than an analytic or meromorphic function. (Unless I have it all wrong).

Comment: @OldJohn: good point.  Could still work, but that would depend a bit on the actual form of $F$.

Comment: @OldJohn, right, I just assumed the function could be extended to the complex plane.